# Clone Magento 2 respository from git causing installing new project not loading existing

Tags: magento2, git

I cloned my magento 2 project from git to a new folder and install and configure the latest database from server, but when i open the magento 2 page in browser it's showing the first step of installing new Magento 2 repository not loading the existing Magento 2, here's my **.gitignore** :

```
/.buildpath
/.cache
/.metadata
/.project
/.settings
atlassian*
/nbproject
/sitemap
/sitemap.xml
/.idea
/.gitattributes
/app/config_sandbox
/app/etc/config.php
/app/etc/env.php
/app/code/Magento/TestModule*
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.actionScriptProperties
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.flexProperties
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.project
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.settings
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.actionScriptProperties
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.flexLibProperties
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.project
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.settings
/.grunt

/pub/media/*.*
!/pub/media/.htaccess
/pub/media/catalog/*
!/pub/media/catalog/.htaccess
/pub/media/customer/*
!/pub/media/customer/.htaccess
/pub/media/downloadable/*
!/pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess
/pub/media/import/*
!/pub/media/import/.htaccess
/pub/media/theme/*
/pub/media/theme_customization/*
!/pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess
/pub/media/wysiwyg/*
!/pub/media/wysiwyg/.htaccess
/pub/media/tmp/*
!/pub/media/tmp/.htaccess
/pub/media/captcha/*
/pub/static/*
!/pub/static/.htaccess

/var/*
!/var/.htaccess
/vendor/*
!/vendor/.htaccess
```